# Solution of my 3rd order differential equation does not plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
F = (x^3)*y'''[x] + (x^2)*y''[x] + x*y'[x] + y[x] - 1
sol = DSolve[{F == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] = -1, y''[0] = 2}, y[x], x]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

No matter how hard I try, I can not plot this function. Help me please

Comment: English,please.

Comment: @Aslan SAB : Executing sol = DSolve[x^3*y'''[x] + (x^2)*y''[x] + x*y'[x] + y[x] - 1 == 0, 
  y[x], x], one sees a Cauchy-Euler ODE of the third order (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Euler_equation).

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is full of syntax issues,

1. `F=...==0`
2. `y'[0] = -1, y''[0] = 2` should be `y'[0] == -1, y''[0] == 2`

I will go straight for `NDSolve`, since you are interested in plotting. BTW, at `x=0` we are having `1/0`, so I have choose starting point to be `10^-5`.

```
F = (x^3)*y'''[x] + (x^2)*y''[x] + x*y'[x] + y[x] - 1 == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{F, y[10^-5] == 1, y'[10^-5] == -1, y''[10^-5] == 2}, y[x], {x, 10^-5, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, 10^-5, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you helped me

Answer (score 1):

Even when I fix the syntax errors in your code, `DSolve` can not find a closed-form solution.

```
DSolve[
  {x^3 y'''[x] + x^2 y''[x] + x y'[x] + y[x] == 1,
   y[0] == 1, y'[0] == -1, y''[0] == 2},
  y[x], x]
```

> `{}`

Therefore, it seems that we will have to accept an approximated solution gotten from `NDSolve` (I actually use the related function `NDSolveValue` for convenince), and even then we will have to deal with a singularity at zero.

```
With[{h = .0001},
  yF = 
    NDSolveValue[
      {x^3 y'''[x] + x^2 y''[x] + x y'[x] + y[x] == 1,
       y[h] == 1, y'[h] == -1, y''[h] == 2},
      y, {x, h, 10}];
  Plot[yF[x], {x, h, 10}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you helped me

Answer (score 0):

The problem under consideration has no solution. Let us find a general solution of the ODE by

```
sol = DSolve[x^3*y'''[x] + (x^2)*y''[x] + x*y'[x] + y[x] -1== 0, y[x], x]
```

> {{y[x] -> 
>      1 + x^Root[1 + 2 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1] C[1] + 
>       x^Root[1 + 2 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2] C[2] + 
>       x^Root[1 + 2 #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3] C[3]}}

Next,

```
N[sol]
```

> {y[x] -> 1. + C[1]/x^0.35321 + x^(1.1766 - 1.20282 I) C[2] + 
>       x^(1.1766 + 1.20282 I) C[3]}}

It's clear the condition

```
y'[0]==-1
```

can't be satisfied because of the singularity at $x=0$.